# Integrating Facebook and Twitter in Xcode Scenes Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, twitter

I have developed a game in Xcode using sprite kit, and scenes. Now I am trying to integrate the functionality to post high scores to twitter and Facebook. I've looked around, and most people say to use SLComposeServiceViewController which is fine, until I try and present it. Because my app really only uses scenes, they never have the member function "presentViewController(....)". Thus, I am unable to ever present it. Anyone know any way around this?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)

    if (touchedNode.name == "tryAgain") {
        let nextScene = Scene_LiveGame(size: self.scene!.size)
        nextScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
        self.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5))
    }
    else if (touchedNode.name == "share") {

        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {

        let fShare = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)



        self.presentViewController(fShare!, animated: true, completion: nil)
         //^This is where my problem is. Xcode is telling me that self has no member function presentViewController which I totally understand, because its a scene and thus doesn't share those functions. But every resource online has shown me this is the only way to do it   

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post the  code you are using (the relevant parts). But in general, you can specify view controller dependant methods in an appropriate view controller, and post notifications from scenes when you want to invoke those methods.

Comment: The code from `else if` block should be replaced with a code that can post a notification. Also it should be moved to an appropriate view controller which has a required member method and which listens for the mentioned notification.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I moved the code to a custom view controller class I made, however I am still unable to call it from my scene.

Comment: The view controller you are talking about, should listen for a notifications posted from the scene. If you are still stuck let me know, and when I get home, I will write an example for you.

Comment: I am still very much stuck. Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not go into `SLComposeViewController` related code. I will just show you two techniques aside from what crashoverride777 proposed. So the first technique would be using notifications, like this:

**GameScene:**

```
import SpriteKit

let kNotificationName = "myNotificationName"

class GameScene: SKScene {


    private func postNotification(named name:String){

        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: name),
                         object: self,
                         userInfo: ["key":"value"]))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        self.postNotification(named: kNotificationName)

    }
}
```

Here, you post a notification by tapping the screen. A desired view controller class can listen for this notification, like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.handle(notification:)),
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kNotificationName),
            object: nil)

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }

    func handle(notification:Notification){
        print("Notification : \(notification)")
    }
}
```

Here, we add self as an observer for this notification - means that when notification happens, an appropriate handling method will be called (and that is our custom `handle(notification:)` method. In that method, you should call your code:

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType:   SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
     let fShare = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
     self.presentViewController(fShare!, animated: true,  completion: nil)
}
```

Actually, I will write another example for delegation, to keep things clean :)

Answer (score 2):

Your are getting this error because you need to present a UIViewController from another UIViewController. So

```
self.presentViewController(...)
```

will not work because self (SKScene) is not a UIViewController. To present from a SKScene you would have to say this

```
view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(fShare!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I would recommend that you do not use those APIs anymore. Its better to use a UIActivityViewController for your sharing needs. This way you only need one share button in your app and you can share to all sorts of services (email, Twitter, Facebook, iMessage, WhatsApp etc).

Create a new Swift file and add this code.

```
enum ShareMenu {

    static func open(text: String, image: UIImage?, appStoreURL: String?, from viewController: UIViewController?) {
        guard let viewController = viewController, let view = viewController.view else { return }

    // Activity items
    var activityItems = [Any]()

    // Text
    activityItems.append(text)

    // Image
    if let image = image {
        activityItems.append(image)
    }

    /// App url
    if let appStoreURL = appStoreURL {
        let items = ActivityControllerItems(appStoreURL: appStoreURL)
        activityItems.append(items)
    }

    // Activity controller
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    // iPad settings
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        activityController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0)
    }

    // Excluded activity types
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        .airDrop,
        .print,
        .assignToContact,
        .addToReadingList,
    ]

    // Present
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        viewController.present(activityController, animated: true)
    }

    // Completion handler
    activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activity, success, items, error) in
        guard success else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            return
        }

            // do something if needed
       }
   } 
}
// MARK: - Activity Controller Items

/**
 ActivityControllerItems
 */
private final class ActivityControllerItems: NSObject {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// App name
    fileprivate let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String ?? "-"

    /// App store web url
    fileprivate let appStoreURL: String

    // MARK: - Init

    /// Init
    fileprivate init(appStoreURL: String) {
        self.appStoreURL = appStoreURL
        super.init()
    }
}

// MARK: - UIActivityItemSource

/// UIActivityItemSource
extension ActivityControllerItems: UIActivityItemSource {

    /// Getting data items

    /// Placeholder item
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return ""
    }

    /// Item for actity type
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        return URL(string: appStoreURL) ?? appName
    }

    /// Provide info about data items

    /// Subject field for services such as email
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return appName
    }
}
```

Than when the share button is pressed you can call it like so

```
 ShareMenu.open(
     text: "Can you beat my score?", 
     image: UIImage(...),  // set to nil if unused
     appStoreURL: "your iTunes app store URL",  // set to nil if unused
     from: view?.window?.rootViewController
 )
```

Bear in mind that the image and appStoreURL will not show up everywhere, it depends on the sharing service.

You can also use your score value from your scene and add it to the text e.g

```
ShareMenu.open( 
     text: "Can you beat my score \(self.score)?",
     ...
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I think UIActivityControllers are the way to go for sharing. You also only need 1 button. I also believe to have read somewhere that those sharing APIs will become deprecated eventually, tho I might be complete wrong here.

Comment: I had never explored UIActivityControllers but absolutely will now. Thank you this clears this up a ton

Comment: You are welcome. As you can see it is pretty straight forward to use. The only trickier bit is adding things like URLs but its not too bad. If you feel my answer helped you could you be so kind to mark it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, this can be done using notifications, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43126735/3402095), or you can go with delegation:

First you should declare the `MyDelegate` protocol which defines one method called `myMethod()`.

```
 protocol MyDelegate:class {

        func myMethod()
    }
```

That method is a requirement that every class must implement if it conforms to this protocl.

In our example, you can look at the scene as a *worker*, and a view controller as a *boss*. When the scene finishes its task, it notifies its boss (delegates responsibilities to him) about job completion, so that boss can decide what is next. I mean, I could say : "The scene is a boss, and it delegates responsibilities to his employee, the view controller..." But it doesn't really matter who you consider as a boss... The [delegation pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276) matters.

So, the view controller, should conform to this protocol, and it will implement the `myMethod()` (that will be called by the scene later):

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK: Conforming to MyDelegate protocol

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            scene.myDelegate = self

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
   }

func myMethod(){
    print("Do your stuff here")
}


 }
```

And here is a code from the `GameScene` where you define the `myDelegate` property that we use to communicate with our view controller:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


   weak var myDelegate:MyDelegate?



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    self.myDelegate?.myMethod()

    }
}
```

To find out when to choose delegation over notifications and vice-versa take a look at [this article](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/05/nsnotificationcenter-vs-delegation-analysis/) (or just search SO, there are some nice posts about that).

Comment: Thank you, this does make sense know. A lot more than it did.